# Measure of the set of points with differential zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a function $f$ which is defined and differentiable on interval $[0,1]$. Let $E=${$x\in [0,1]| f'(x)=0$}. Then the measure $m(f(E))$ would be zero.

At first, I tried to prove this statement by showing that $E$ is at most countable. But my professor told me that $E$ may not be countable. Then I noticed it's a special case of Sard's theorem which states that the measure of cirtical set is zero. But proofs in the paper are rather complicated. Is there any simpler proof corresponds to this specific question? Thanks.

Really sorry for my mistake in the question. It should be $m(f(E))$ instead of $m(E)$.

Comment: As it stands, this is nonsense. Consider a constant function.

Comment: My mistake has been corrected.

Comment: Now this is the result of Sard's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, what if we consider the function $f(x)=1/2-x$ on $[0,1/2]$ and $f(x)=0$ on $(1/2,1)$ and integrate it? Then $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ is non-constant, differentiable and $F'(x)=f(x)$, hence the measure of the set on which $F'$ is $0$ is non-zero.

Comment: Thank you for your counterexample. But my question has been corrected.